# CSS styling removed from page

Tags: html, css, header, styling

I'm working on a website right now, the homepage links up with the CSS as normal and displays fine. The about page for no apparent reason is not connecting to the style.css, the same header links are there as the homepage has, apart from an additional two stylesheets just to get two web-fonts to work. Can someone have a look and see any issues with this.

I've copied everything within the pages header.

INDEX

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Naked Radish</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The Naked Radish">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
```

ABOUT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Naked Radish</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The Naked Radish">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/jennasue-webfont/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/quickendjerk-webfont/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
```

Index - http://www.jordancharters.co.uk/nakedradish

About - http://www.jordancharters.co.uk/nakedradish/about.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your stylesheet: it is in a different language. Specify either of the following:

**HTML**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

[image]

**UPDATE..** It seems as though you are using a relative URL for the stylesheet.. both pages are in different folders.. try setting an absolute URL? Let me know if that works.

Use this: `<link href="http://www.jordancharters.co.uk/nakedradish/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

Comment: @mcvities It seems as though you are using a relative URL for the stylesheet.. both pages are in different folders.. try setting an absolute URL? Let me know if that works.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean sorry :/.

Comment: @mcvities use this `<link href="http://www.jordancharters.co.uk/nakedradish/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

Comment: Actually, both pages are in the same folder; you're forgetting about the implied `/index.html`. Mcvities, your pages are currently looking for a css file in a place relative to the page's own position in the filesystem. If you had another page at, say, `jordancharters.co.uk/nakedradish/food/recipe.html`, it wouldn't be able to find the CSS the way you're writing the URLs.

Comment: Oh I see. Hmm I get the idea of this but no reason why my relative url right now isn't working. Plus not great idea to be restricted to a specific url like that I guess. Appreciate the idea, just need to figure out a solution to the issue another way.

Comment: I changed to ../css/ isn't that a suitable solution, come out to the root then search. Just added this a second ago anyway to test.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to change to `/nakedradish/css/style.css`. By starting the URL with a single slash, it'll assume you want the same `http://www.jordancharters.co.uk` as the parent page.

Comment: I've just been playing with my coders encoding options. Switched everything to UTF-8 in the program (Coda).

Comment: @mcvities i got it to work.. remove the slash before 'css'.. use this: `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` only for that one.. keep the forward slashes on all the others.

Comment: Grr, what the hell. I think its some encoding issue then maybe.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190078/stylesheet-taken-over-replaced-by-chinese-characters

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've gone through and made sure all files are UTF-8, some wern't so it's all certainly UTF-8 now. Although their should be a custom web-font being used on the page title and quote (head chef -ed. and the quote below).

Comment: Yep. Done! Amazing support form you both, thank you very much! :) Mainly the UTF-16 issue. Switched it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

It... *looks* like you've got some kind of encoding glitch on your about page, which is making browsers think that the CSS is encoded in a way that it isn't. Here's a brief excerpt of what my browser thinks your CSS says, when loaded as part of the about page:

```
⼪⁓瑹汥⁒敳整‪⼊੡牴楣汥Ⱐ慳楤攬⁦楧畲攬⁦潯瑥爬⁨敡摥爬⁨杲潵瀬⁭敮甬⁮慶Ⱐ獥捴楯渠笊।楳灬慹㨠
```

It kind of goes on like that for a while. The raw network response for the html isn't much better:

```
ÿþ<�!�D�O�C�T�Y�P�E� �h�t�m�l�>�
```

Although it appears that the browser can compensate for that part - you'll notice there's a `DOCTYPE html` hiding in between those garbage characters. And then it switches encodings or something partway through, and starts looking perfectly normal.

Comment: Do you think specifying a charset would fix this? I put that as my answer.

Comment: Quite possibly. I'd give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried and uploaded. I don't see any change, do you by anychance? Refreshing the browser cache too.

Comment: Hmm. Still looks broken to me (using Firefox). Where did those first two characters (`ÿþ<!DOCTYPE html>`) come from? Try taking them out.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it loads but It's the Unicode problem ,set The unicode in your your HTML , and save your CSS again with standard Unicode