# PHP/HTML file content replaced by Chinese characters upon uploading it to a webserver

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190078/stylesheet-taken-over-replaced-by-chinese-characters). My .php file is almost completely replaced with Chinese characters after I upload it to a web server.

In the question linked above, the issue is solved by changing all the linked files to UTF-8. However as you can see in the **Local** code I already apply `charset="UTF-8"` to every linked file and the index.php file itself is also UTF-8 by defining `<meta charset="UTF-8">` at the top.

Local:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/minecraft-webfont.css" charset="UTF-8" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css" charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
```

After uploading it to a web server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    㰀栀琀洀氀㸀
      <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        㰀洀攀琀愀渀愀洀攀㴀∀瘀椀攀眀瀀漀爀琀挀漀渀琀攀渀琀㴀∀眀椀搀琀栀㴀搀攀瘀椀挀攀ⴀ眀椀搀琀栀椀渀椀琀椀愀氀ⴀ猀挀愀氀攀㴀∀㸀

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/minecraft-webfont.css" charset="UTF-8" >
        㰀氀椀渀欀 爀攀氀㴀猀琀礀氀攀猀栀攀攀琀栀爀攀昀㴀∀栀琀琀瀀猀㨀挀搀渀樀猀⸀挀氀漀甀搀昀氀愀爀攀⸀挀漀洀
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/remodal/remodal.css" charset="UTF-8">
        㰀氀椀渀欀 爀攀氀㴀∀猀琀礀氀攀猀栀攀攀琀栀爀攀昀㴀∀挀猀猀
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" charset="UTF-8">
      </head>
```

As a result it looks like any PHP code in the `<body>` is being commented out and not working. Does anyone have any idea how this can happen? I'm totally stuck here!

Comment: Did you try the answer in the question you linked?

Comment: The stated question and answers also talk about the file being encoded differently on the server once it was uploaded, which appears to be the case. Did you check that?

Comment: Turn off static compression if there is such option on your server.

Comment: Check if your file starts with a BOM and remove it if it does. UTF8 categorically does *not* use a BOM despite many editors' insistence on adding it to UTF8 files.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys! Unfortunately I do not have the power to edit the server settings since it's a hired host, but I will contact them and update everyone here after the problem is solved.