# chrome can't use local css for a simple local site

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having a weird problem. 
I am trying to build my github page site. So I am writing my html locally and then push it online to see it.
The problem is that Chrome doesn't recognize my css file when I am opening it locally. When I push the changers online or I am using another browser it work just fine

Here is how I import it on my index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

 </head>
```

And  when I go to the chrome dev tools
[css have turned to chinese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/976G3.png)

Microsoft edge load the css file normally.
I have tried a couple of different things like:

- Using another editor
- Creating the file in different directory
- trying different filenames
- Clearing Chromes Cache

Nothing seems to work
I have loaded again a local a site like this and it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: possibly an encoding problem. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190078/stylesheet-taken-over-replaced-by-chinese-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the file encoding is UTF-8. You can use iconv or just in your text editor > save as.

Comment: I use sublime text and i don't see an encoding option listed but i adde '@charset "UTF-8";' and works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @than_g I think it shows in the status bar on sublime