# My CSS is not being applied to my html, how do i fix it?

Tags: html, css

So i have this weird problem that any css i write doesn't work. I tried to create multiple pages and link css but it simply doesn't apply.
If i download a template of the internet if i run the page, their html works.

Here is an example of the most basic code i've written that doesn't work, even though i've run it through validators. It doesn't matter what element im trying to apply styling to it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Test Page </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Sup! </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #61122f;
}
```

I have tried numerous solutions i've found online, but none of them work.

Comment: I'm not sure but have tried to refresh your HTML page with Ctrl+F5 key combination? It clears the cache of your browser, so it will request your style.css again and it will get the updated version of it. If this doesn't work, try inspecting your body tag with F12.

Comment: Right click your page and click on View Source. Click on the style.css , see if it opens up your css file. If it doesn't, the path you've set is wrong.

Comment: @M.ÇağlarTUFAN Nothing happens when i refresh. This is the body tag when inspected. https://imgur.com/GSa3a7L  Doesn't even load my stylesheet im guessing.

Comment: @Gosi It opens my css file.

Comment: @Vexane If it opens up with all your CSS code in it, then your path is right. Most probably its just some cache issue.

Comment: @Vexane Is your `style.css` in the same directory, with correct extension?

Comment: @TechySharnav Yes. Tried to even move it to a folder and link to that, still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finnaly figured it out. The encoding was set to utf-16 and everything rendered as chinese kanji. This is the problem solution. [Stylesheet taken-over/replaced by Chinese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190078/stylesheet-taken-over-replaced-by-chinese-characters)

Answer (score 2):

Can you check your network tab that your style.css is fetched from server and there is no 404 not found.

I would say try "/styles.css"

Comment: Already tried adding "/" basically everywhere to try and find if it works but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Check your Devtool, see if any error in network, make sure that `style.css` successfully loaded.

### 2. Try - Importing External Style Sheets

Write in html head tag:

```css
<style>
    @import url("css/style.css");
    p {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Tried both. There are no errors in the network tab and nothing hapens when i add that code.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has given almost everything that I know. Sometimes its the silly things that we missed out that gives us tough time. Do try and follow this:

1. make sure both the html and css are under the same folder, in my case the folder is named "ROUGH"
2. Check for any white spaces before and after the file name. Example: "style " has one white space after the name, it should just be "style"
3. Using "/" inside the href. Example below href = "/style.css"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I believe the problem was coming from the name of my CSS folder in which I had the CSS file. The folder was named "CSS", I'm not sure why it was causing issues but when I put my css file into my "js" folder it worked perfectly fine. Then I created a new folder named "myCSS" and it worked still. This is a weird workaround but it solved my issue and it may be useful to someone else.

also for the link I just had  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS/style.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the folder structure. So maybe try and make sure your html file and css file are on the same level.

Or you could try "../styles.css" - Again this depends on where your files are in your dir

Comment: Already tried, didn't work. Tried multiple different locations for the css file none of them worked.

Comment: Could we see a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: https://imgur.com/RakajpN They are in a folder on my desktop.

Comment: I've tried your code and it all works fine https://imgur.com/a/eVXlSDa

Comment: strange I literally put the same setup you have in your question on my desktop and it worked smoothly. As shown in the screenshot. What you can also try is maybe on a different OS or try put it in a seperate folder and then just open the index.html and see the output from there